# modulus optimization in c

Tags: c, optimization, modulus

I'm trying to do optimization of modulus operation on set of integers I know ahead
The dividers are 400-3500, And the dividends are positive integers up to 2^16

I heard about magic numbers on hacker's delight but I couldn't find a way to get magic numbers for modulus for general numbers.

And if not by magic numbers, can I do optimizations based on the information I have on the numbers?

Comment: That a-priori knowledge is pretty vague.  I doubt that you can utilize it any better than the compiler will do anyway if you are using the type system correctly.  Be sure to enable the compiler's optimizations.

Comment: There is no single magic number for all moduli, but you can prepare an array of them to cover all your cases.

Comment: @5gon12eder it can only do that if it knows the modulus, and it's doesn't, because it's variable

Comment: You should not care, and leave such micro-optimizations to the compiler. Most compilers are able to optimize a division or a modulus by a contant number

Comment: We are talking about a processor made 30 years ago, I don't think the compiler I'm using  is optimized for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mention Hackers Delight, and it has the answer. See the section Integer Division by Constants, Incorporation into a Compiler (Unsigned). Implement that.

Then, of course, don't run that every time you do a modulus, that would be much worse than a naive modulus. Make an array of the results you get for 400-3500, then when calculating the modulus, take the parameters from that array.

The code given there is

```
struct mu {unsigned M;     // Magic number, 
          int a;           // "add" indicator, 
          int s;};         // and shift amount. 

struct mu magicu(unsigned d) {
                           // Must have 1 <= d <= 2**32-1. 
   int p; 
   unsigned nc, delta, q1, r1, q2, r2; 
   struct mu magu; 

   magu.a = 0;             // Initialize "add" indicator. 
   nc = -1 - (-d)%d;       // Unsigned arithmetic here. 
   p = 31;                 // Init. p. 
   q1 = 0x80000000/nc;     // Init. q1 = 2**p/nc. 
   r1 = 0x80000000 - q1*nc;// Init. r1 = rem(2**p, nc). 
   q2 = 0x7FFFFFFF/d;      // Init. q2 = (2**p - 1)/d. 
   r2 = 0x7FFFFFFF - q2*d; // Init. r2 = rem(2**p - 1, d). 
   do {
      p = p + 1; 
      if (r1 >= nc - r1) {
         q1 = 2*q1 + 1;            // Update q1. 
         r1 = 2*r1 - nc;}          // Update r1. 
      else {
         q1 = 2*q1; 
         r1 = 2*r1;} 
      if (r2 + 1 >= d - r2) {
         if (q2 >= 0x7FFFFFFF) magu.a = 1; 
         q2 = 2*q2 + 1;            // Update q2. 
         r2 = 2*r2 + 1 - d;}       // Update r2. 
      else {
         if (q2 >= 0x80000000) magu.a = 1; 
         q2 = 2*q2; 
         r2 = 2*r2 + 1;} 
      delta = d - 1 - r2; 
   } while (p < 64 && 
           (q1 < delta || (q1 == delta && r1 == 0))); 

   magu.M = q2 + 1;        // Magic number 
   magu.s = p - 32;        // and shift amount to return 
   return magu;            // (magu.a was set above). 
}
```

The way to get the modulo of a number `x` by `y` is then something like (not tested, check it)

```
uint64_t n = x;
// do division
n = ((n + magic[y].a) * magic[y].M) >> (32 + magic[y].s);
// get remainder
return x - y * n;
```

You can probably do better than this using 16bit magic numbers, so no 64bit integers would be involved.

Comment: I saw an implementation suggestion for div, are you sure there is also an algorithm for mod?

Comment: @user1368177 it's the same thing. Divide, then multiply again, and subtract from the original.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check the improvement by using this

Comment: btw, do you have an implementation of the multiplicitve? And also, is divide and multiply still an optimization over a simple %?

Comment: @user1368177 implementation of what? And yes probably. While the "divide using magic numbers" routine (not the above code, which just computes the parameters) looks complicated, an actual division or modulo (ie using the `div` instruction) is at least 9 cycles just by itself on common processors, and not pipelined.

Comment: implementation of magic number for multiplication. or is it the same number?
and also, is this the way to use the magic number? :
res = x & magic_number;
res = (res >> s) + a; if so, how do you use it for multiplication?

Comment: @user1368177 multiply by the divisor, remember you're doing `x % y = x - x / y * y`, just with the division implemented differently. I'll edit it in

Comment: so I understand multiplication is not an expensive operation.  And if I want to implement magic numbers for 16 bit I guess I need to use p = 15, and q1 = 0x8000

Comment: i had to change to p = 63
i'll try it with 16bit

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> n = ((n + magic[y].a) * magic[y].M) >> (32 + magic[y].s);
> ```

This doesn't work when the add indicator is 1. Following Hacker's Delight (section 10-10), the quota (here denoted `q`) is computed as:

```
q = floor(M*n/2^32)
q = q >> s
```

if `a` = 0, and

```
q = floor(M*n/2^32)
t = (q+n)>>1    // (q+n)/2
q = t >> (s-1)
```

if `a` = 1. This can be written as:

```
q = ((M*n)>>32 + a*n) >> s
```

or, following harold's notation:

```
n = (((n * magic[y].M) >> 32) + n * magic[y].a) >> magic[y].s;
```

Answer (score -2):

Recommend the below as the only helpful thing that can be passed to the compiler is knowledge that the operands are in a limited 16 bit range.  Else let the compiler optimize.

```
#include <stdint.h>
inline uint_fast16_t fast_mod(uint_fast16_t dividend, uint_fast16_t divisor) {
  return dividend % divisor;
}
```